# Is it possible to access the Svelte store from web console?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-store

I'm debugging the Svelte app and wondering if it is possible to access svelte data in the store from the web console? Does somebody know if it is possible, if it yes, how pls :)

And by the way, we are still using svelte 1.

Answer (score 4):

Following is a neat way to access store:

1.Define a property (ex: `store`) on window object and have its getter to log the store data.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "store", {
    get : _ => {
        environmentV2.subscribe(e => console.log(e))
    }
});
```

2.Type `store` in your console and press enter. You will see the store data as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

During initialization you can assign the store to the document object:

`document.sveltestore = mystore;`

this will work for svelte 1 & 2

Answer (score 0):

You can access the props, state and store with the [*official* svelte browser extension](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-devtools)

- [Svelte Devtools for **Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/svelte-devtools/ckolcbmkjpjmangdbmnkpjigpkddpogn)
- [Svelte Devtools for **Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/svelte-devtools/)

Comment: Not maintained anymore, doesn't work in latest chrome

Comment: @Eskel, FYI - looks like this has been [taken over by SvelteJs](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-devtools), is now under active maintenance, and works in the latest version of chrome.